# sonatype nexus 3. Gorgeously slow download of maven-metadata.xml

Tags: java, maven, devops, nexus

I have two maven repositories with ~20 project in each. Artifact download from it goes well (like 67mb in 7 seconds). But when I try to download maven-metadata.xml, it can take from 5 to 10 seconds. Size of this file is about 4 kb.

I do not have any proxy repositories and no routing is set up.

**And one more important thing** - first maven repo and projects in it - for releases every project there has about 10 artifacts. maven-metadata.xml from this repo is served fast. Second  one is snapshot repository is for snapshots artifacts, and every project here has about ~100 artifacts and download of maven-metadata.xml from any project in this repository takes 5-10 seconds.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you downloading it?  I assume the time is consistent.  Is the file in use when you are downloading it?  Like is the repo super busy?  I can see how it'd finish building before passing you the file.

Comment: Hello! I just open this file in browser. And no server is just idle..

Comment: That is weird.  I'm curious if it's equally slow using curl to take the browser out of the equation.  You could also try incogntio browser but I would prefer curl because it could be your browser setting.  For example in mind, the xml loads rather than downloads.  So already we're different :)

Comment: Yes. I tried to use curl and did it just from nexus (localhost) - same situation, same time to download it